# Access Denied from Cloudfront with Secure Cookies returns no CORS headers preventing reading error information from a XHR request

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using cloudfront secure cookies to keep some files private. When cookie auth succeeds and the origin is hit cloudfront returns the proper cors headers (Access-Control-Allow-Origin) from the origin but how do I make cloudfront return CORS headers during a 403/Access Denied? This validation is entirely in cloudfront before the request to the origin, but is there a setting to enable it? I want to be able to make a XHR request to cloudfront and know why the request failed. Since cloudfront doesn't return cors headers on a 403 most modern browsers will prevent reading any information on the request including the status code and its tough to determine why the request failed.

Thanks!

Comment: So you want the CORS headers just so that you can see the 403 error programmatically?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot yup, I want to know if its a 403 or auth is valid and its a 404.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you know, CloudFront doesn't spontaneously emit CORS headers -- they need to come from the origin server -- so in order to see CORS headers in the response, the request needs to be allowed by CloudFront... but, of course, it can't be allowed, because the condition you're trying to catch is `403 Forbidden`.

So, what we need in order to allow your unauthorized responses to be CORS-friendly is an additional origin that can provide us with an alternate error response, and that origin needs to be CORS-aware.  The solution seems to be something we can accomplish with a little help from CloudFront [Custom Error Responses](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/custom-error-pages.html) and an otherwise-empty S3 bucket, created for the purpose.

Custom error responses allow you to configure CloudFront to fetch the custom error response from another origin, rather than generating it internally.  As part of that process, some headers from the original request are included in the upstream fetch, and the response headers from the error document are returned.

S3 makes a handy origin, since it has configurable CORS support.

- Create a new, empty bucket.
- Enable CORS for the bucket, and configure CORS with the appropriate parameters.  The default configuration may be fine for this purpose.
- Create a simple file that your CloudFront distribution will be using instead of its built in response for a 403.  For test purposes, that can just be a text file that says "Access denied."
- Upload the file to the bucket with whatever name you like, such as `403.txt`.  Select the option to make the object publicly-readable.  Set metadata `Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, private, must-revalidate` and `Content-Type: text/plain` (or `text/html`, depending on what exactly you put in the error file).
- In CloudFront, create a new Origin.  For the Origin Domain Name, select the bucket from the list of buckets.
- Create a new Cache Behavior, matching path `/403.txt` (or whatever you named the file).  Whitelist the `Origin`, `Access-Control-Request-Headers`, and `Access-Control-Request-Method` headers for forwarding.  Set Restrict Viewer Access to No, because for this one path, we don't require signed credentials.  Note that this path needs to be exactly the same as the filename in the bucket (except the leading slash, which isn't shown in the bucket but should be included, here).
- In CloudFront Custom Error Responses, choose Create Custom Error Response.  Select error code 403, set Error Caching Minimum TTL to 0, choose Customize Error Response Yes, set Response Page Path `/403.txt` and set HTTP Response code to 403.
- Profit!

Test:

```
$ curl -v dzczcnnnnexample.cloudfront.net -H 'Origin: http://example.com'
* Rebuilt URL to: dzczcnnnnexample.cloudfront.net/
*   Trying 203.0.113.208...
* Connected to dzczcnnnnexample.cloudfront.net (203.0.113.208) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: dzczcnnnnexample.cloudfront.net
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> Origin: http://example.com
>
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Content-Length: 16
< Connection: keep-alive
< Date: Sun, 08 Apr 2018 14:01:25 GMT
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, HEAD
< Access-Control-Max-Age: 3000
< Last-Modified: Sun, 08 Apr 2018 13:29:19 GMT
< ETag: "fd9e8f7be7b65381c4acc272b6afc858"
< x-amz-server-side-encryption: AES256
< Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Server: AmazonS3
< Vary: Origin,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Access-Control-Request-Method
< X-Cache: Error from cloudfront
< Via: 1.1 1234567890a26beddeac6bfc77b2d348.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
< X-Amz-Cf-Id: ExAmPlEIbQBtaqExamPLEQs4VwcxhvtU1YXBi47uUzUgami0Hj0MwQ==
<
Access denied.
* Connection #0 to host dzczcnnnnexample.cloudfront.net left intact
```

Here, `Access denied.` is what I put in the text file I created.  You may want to get a little more creative, after confirming that this works for you, as it does for me.  The content of this new file in S3 will always be returned whenever CloudFront throws a 403 error.  Additionally, it will also be returned whenever your origin throws a 403, because custom error responses are designed to replace all errors with a given HTTP status code.

You note, above, that we see `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`.  This is the default behavior of S3 CORS.  If you provide explicit origins in the S3 CORS config, you get a response like this...

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com
```

...but for `GET` requests, I assume this level of specificity would not be necessary and the wildcard would suffice.  The scenario described here isn't setting CORS for the entire CloudFront distribution -- just for the error response.